# Spotify Session Renewal Issue

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I'm trying to use spotify inside my iOS app and so far so good. After a user logs in and gives me the requested scopes, I'm storing the session and they can use everything inside the app. The issue arrives after 60 minutes when the access token is expired. At that point I'm retrieving a 401, and I'm calling my function to renew my accesstoken but somehow this doesn't work at all.

```
private let sessionManager = AppDelegate().sessionManager

func initiateSpotifySession() {
    let requestedScopes: SPTScope = [.playlistModifyPublic, .playlistModifyPrivate, .ugcImageUpload]
    sessionManager.initiateSession(with: requestedScopes, options: .default)
}

func renewSpotifySession() {
    let session = loadSpotifySession()

    if session != nil {
        sessionManager.renewSession()
    } else {
        print("login required")
    }
}
```

The `initiateSpotifySession` works perfectly, but as soon as I request the `sessionManager.renewSession()` function it doesn't work. There is no error coming up and the following delegate isn't being called either;

```
func sessionManager(manager: SPTSessionManager, didRenew session: SPTSession) {
    print("running the renewal")
}
```

My iOS app console logs something like; 
`Task <C4C4A6C0-64D7-49EC-81AF-D6E581CD27AE>.<1> finished with error - code: -999`, but that's it.

The refresh token is available and I can print it. Somehow the renewSession just doesn't work.

The server that I'm using for refreshing and retrieving is the 1 step click Heroku one provided by Spotify in their quick start guide.

Comment: No crashes or anything like that? Is there a delegate method for an error?

Comment: Yea, there is, and I'm having a print statement over there as well but that isn't throwing anything either.

Comment: Yeah if nothing is failing, unless someone has encountered this exact same issue before I'm not sure how you can move forward. Maybe contact Spotify? Could be a bug in their system. You could also use an application like Charles proxy to inspect the response and see what kinda response Spotify is giving you which might give you a hint as to what is going on.

Comment: Hm, fair enough. Will try to run an empty project with just the renew function tonight. If that's not working either, I'll contact Spotify themselves and ask them what's going on. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Created a sample project. It is working whenever I call the renew function immediately inside the initiate function. As soon as I request the renew function outside of that it returns the -999. I can post more of the code in my original question, if you still interested in solving this problem @CharlieFish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it. I was storing my session, but forgot to reassign it to the sessionManager. This way my session was always nil and when requesting the renewal there was no refresh token which caused it to not return a new access token.

Solved it by reassigning the session!